# Calculate duration for bookings in a period between two time slots

Tags: mysql

In a booking system I want to calculate the sum of hours a resource has been booked between two dates (2019-01-01 to 2019-01-02) from 8am to 4pm.

I managed to calculate the sum of hours a resource has been booked if the booking doesn't last more than one day. The problem arises if the booking last more than one day.

With the following booking I expect the result to be 9.5 hours.

```
startDatetime           endDatetime
2019-01-01 14:30:00     2019-01-02 18:30:00
```

This is the code I have tried:

```
SELECT resourceID, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(sum(LEAST(TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(endDatetime)), TIME_TO_SEC('16:00')) - GREATEST(TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(startDatetime)), TIME_TO_SEC('08:00')))) AS totalTimeBooked 
FROM booking 
WHERE startDatetime BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-01-02 23:59:59'
  AND (TIME(startDatetime) BETWEEN '08:00' AND '16:00' 
    OR TIME(endDatetime) BETWEEN '08:00' AND '16:00')
group by resourceID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution to get the `booked_time` for each `resourceID`:

```
SELECT
  resourceID,
  SEC_TO_TIME(
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DATE(endDatetime), DATE(startDatetime)) = 0 THEN
        GREATEST(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(LEAST('16:00:00', TIME(endDatetime)), LEAST(GREATEST('08:00:00', TIME(startDatetime)), '16:00:00'))), 0)
      ELSE
        TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('16:00:00', LEAST(GREATEST('08:00:00', TIME(startDatetime)), '16:00:00')))
        + TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(GREATEST('08:00:00', LEAST('16:00:00', TIME(endDatetime))), '08:00:00'))
        + ((DATEDIFF(DATE(endDatetime), DATE(startDatetime)) - 1) * TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('16:00:00', '08:00:00')))
      END
    )
  ) AS booked_time
FROM table_name
GROUP BY resourceID
```

You can use the following query to get the result for each row (useful to test the above query):

```
SELECT
  resourceID, startDatetime, endDatetime,
  SEC_TO_TIME(
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DATE(endDatetime), DATE(startDatetime)) = 0 THEN
      GREATEST(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(LEAST('16:00:00', TIME(endDatetime)), LEAST(GREATEST('08:00:00', TIME(startDatetime)), '16:00:00'))), 0)
    ELSE
      TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('16:00:00', LEAST(GREATEST('08:00:00', TIME(startDatetime)), '16:00:00')))
      + TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(GREATEST('08:00:00', LEAST('16:00:00', TIME(endDatetime))), '08:00:00'))
      + ((DATEDIFF(DATE(endDatetime), DATE(startDatetime)) - 1) * TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('16:00:00', '08:00:00')))
    END
  ) AS booked_time
FROM table_name
ORDER BY resourceID, startDatetime, endDatetime
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.com**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=00f258083b0127a578fe7840154a32fc)

---

**Note:** You have to be careful using the [`SEC_TO_TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) function. On a large amount of data or big date ranges you can reach the maximum value of the [`TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html) datatype:

> MySQL retrieves and displays `TIME` values in '`HH:MM:SS`' format (or '`HHH:MM:SS`' format for large hours values). `TIME` values may range from '`-838:59:59`' to '`838:59:59`'. The hours part may be so large because the `TIME` type can be used not only to represent a time of day (which must be less than 24 hours), but also elapsed time or a time interval between two events (which may be much greater than 24 hours, or even negative).
>   **source:** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html

---

You also asked how to get the occupancy rate. You can use the following solution using the above query:

```
SELECT
  resourceID,
  booked_time,
  CONCAT((TIME_TO_SEC(booked_time) / TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('16:00:00', '08:00:00')) * 100), '%') AS 'occupancy_rate'
FROM (
  SELECT
    resourceID,
    SEC_TO_TIME(
      SUM(
        CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DATE(endDatetime), DATE(startDatetime)) = 0 THEN
          GREATEST(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(LEAST('16:00:00', TIME(endDatetime)), LEAST(GREATEST('08:00:00', TIME(startDatetime)), '16:00:00'))), 0)
        ELSE
          TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('16:00:00', LEAST(GREATEST('08:00:00', TIME(startDatetime)), '16:00:00')))
          + TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(GREATEST('08:00:00', LEAST('16:00:00', TIME(endDatetime))), '08:00:00'))
          + ((DATEDIFF(DATE(endDatetime), DATE(startDatetime)) - 1) * TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('16:00:00', '08:00:00')))
        END
      )
    ) AS booked_time
  FROM table_name
  GROUP BY resourceID
) t_occupancy_rate
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eb492a853b31e76725ee9fa843718508)

Comment: Let me start of by saying that I'm sorry that we didn't get back to you earlier. Is has been a hectic past 6 months. :) Thank you so much for your response. It was a huge help. I have marked your response as the answer now. Can you help us figure out the last part we are missing. Is it possible to group on hours in a way that would result in 8:00-09:00 bookedTime 0:30, 09:00-10:00 bookedTime 1:00, 10:00-11:00 bookedTime 0:00 and so on?